# google maps change navigation map controller

Tags: image, google-maps, navigation

ok so i have a google map store locator and i want to switch the image it calls for the zoomer and all the little tools... heres what it looks like i know everyone knows...

http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/mapcontrols3d5.png

i want to change the stock one with one of my own.. is that possible with jquery or something

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation at the [custom controls](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls).

The way i do it is by creating a div in my page and then add it like this inside the map

```
var mapControl=document.getElementById("yourCustomControlDiv");
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(mapControl);
```